# Modify variables by accessing android webview setting in .net maui

Tags: c#, android, android-webview, maui, .net-7.0

I found out that the viewport setting of the site displayed in the web view control of the android app developed with maui was ignored.
Therefore, it is necessary to set the setUseWideViewPort setting to true in the webview control setting.
But I haven't used xamarin either and maui has been used for 2 days.
How can I access this setting to modify the value?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setUseWideViewPort(boolean)

I found the reason for ignoring the viewport meta tag, but I don't know how to set the value not to ignore it

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=1920" />
I hope the above meta tag works in the Android app webview

Comment: You can try the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Handlers to set `setUseWideViewPort`.

Create a `MyWebview` class derived from WebView:

```
namespace MauiApp1.Resources.Controls
{
    class MyWebview:WebView
    {
    }
}
```

Use `MyWebview` in .xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.Resources.Controls"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">

   <Controls:MyWebview Source="https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui"/>

</ContentPage>
```

You can then customize the `WebViewHandler`, via its property mapper, to perform the desired modification only to `MyWebview` instances:

```
using MauiApp1.Resources.Controls;

namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ModifyWebview();    
    }

    void ModifyWebview()
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (Handler, View) =>
        {
            if (View is MyWebview)
            {
#if ANDROID
              Handler.PlatformView.Settings.UseWideViewPort= true;
#endif
            }
        });

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found another way to apply `UseWideViewPort` to the entire `BlazorWebView` without any custom classes or handlers in MAUI:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoadedAsync;
    }

    protected async void OnLoadedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if ANDROID
        var androidWebview = blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
        androidWebview.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
        androidWebview.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
#endif
}
```

And don't forget to set  desired resolution like this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1920" />` in `index.html`

Comment: I struggled with lots of other posts. This worked awesomely for me to override the header and via androidWebview.LoadUrl